# TALEND : while moving employee data from source to target I want to remove duplicates and move them to separate file

Tags: talend

TALEND :  while moving employee data from source to target I want to remove duplicates and move them to separate file

Comment: Hi - whats your definition of duplicate? Same employee id or identical values in every field of the employee records? When there is a duplicate do you want to move all the records for that employee to a separate file or 1 record to the main target and any others to the separate file; if so, which of the records goes to which target?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly if the full record is same its a duplicate

like there could be 2 scenarios

1. duplicate records in the source file
2. Duplicate records in the source file when compared with   existing table.

duplicate in source file :
if there are 3 duplicate records
catch the first record and move it to target and other 2 move them to another file (may be u shd add a surrogate key to identify them uniquely)

duplicate rec compared with table data :
compare each rec with table data and if its duplicate move it to another file